# Making a cell mandatory based on conditional formatting of other cells part 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am looking to achieve the following:

Column C has been conditionally formatted based on data entry that if data is out of range, cell background will turn red.

I am wanting to force data entry at the bottom of the sheet via a mandatory inputbox whenever data has been entered and the cell is conditionally formatted red due to out of range data.In this example, the comment is made in cell B101. How would I alter the code below so that if B101 already contains text, then the comment is made in B102, and if B102 contains text, the comment is made in B103 and so on.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)
If target.rows.count > 1 Or target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
  Exit Sub
End if

Dim com As String
Dim comm1 As String

Set isect = Application.Intersect(target,Range("C1:C100"))
If isect Is Nothing Then

Else

If target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0) Then
   com = "Enter comment at bottom of sheet"

   Do While comm1 = ""
     comm1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:=com, Type:=2)
     On Error GoTo myloop
     If comm1 = False Then
        comm1 = ""
     End If

myloop:
   On Error GoTo -1
   Loop
   Range("B101").Value = comm1

Else
   Range("B101").value = ""
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add in a Do While loop:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 101

Do While Range("B" & i).Value <> ""
    Debug.Print Range("B" & i).Address
    i = i + 1
Loop
' Now that we're out of the loop, the next cell will be empty
Range("B" & i).Value = "Comment here"
```

Edit: Or, you could just do `Range("B101").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Value = "Comment Here"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the 'Range("B101").value=comm1  Else Range("B101").value=""  ' with your original post and it seems to be working well.